# How do I host a file on my server for download?

Tags: download, ftp, hosting

This might be a stupid question, but I have to ask cause I'm not getting anywhere...

I have a virtual private server with Godaddy, and I set up an FTP account.  When I access the account via ftp I see these folders:

anon_ftp
cgi-bin
error_docs
httpdocs
httpsdocs
private
statistics
subdomains
vault_scripts
web_users
.Security (file)

Now, what I want to do is place a file on this server where people can just navigate to a URL and download the file.  For example, mywebsite.com/music/somesong.mp3.

How do I do this?  Do I just create a folder in that location called "music" and then upload the file to that folder?  If so, I'm getting error "550 music: Access is denied" is this a permissions error because this user is admin so whats the deal?

---

**UPDATE**

The file I'm trying to make available for download is a .jad

I've put the file in /httpdocs/BB but I keep getting this error when accessing:

"HTTP Status 404 - /BB/plugin.jad

type Status report

message /BB/plugin.jad

description The requested resource (/BB/plugin.jad) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.16"

---

**UPDATE 2**

I spoke with Godaddy and they said I need to configure the MIME type as an application/octet-stream.  They tell me I have to do it but don't tell me how, so how is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is how to configure a MIME type in IIS http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758256%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall GoDaddy having some form of tech support. If you have a VPS that should get you at least some level of competent person to help you.

Assuming the root url (`example.com`) is pointing to your `httpdocs` directory, you would upload your `music` folder to `/httpdocs`. Then the web address would be `www.example.com/music/song.mp3`. It's possible GoDaddy has a `.htaccess` file prohibiting you (or anyone else for that matter) from accessing a `.mp3` file.

I would also check the `error_docs` directory and see if you're getting any serverside errors.

Comment: Thanks, godaddy support was actually pretty useful.  I figured out how to configure a MIME type in IIS here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758256%28WS.10%29.aspx.  Work's like a charm now.

Comment: JAD: text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor, JAR: application/java-archive, and COD: application/vnd.rim.cod instead of application/octet-stream makes the file .jad installable on Blackberry

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the file via http then you should probably put the music folder into the httpdocs folder. If that doesn't work then it might be some subfolder in the subdomains folder.

Comment: I'm not able to access the file once I put it in this folder, I'm getting the error message stated above in the Update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache as the web server, you could create a .htaccess file in the directory where your .jad file is.

Put the following into the .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .jad
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the `anon_ftp` directory for anonymous ftp. Otherwise, for `http://www.example.com/music/mysong.mp3` to work, put create `/httpdocs/music` and put `mysong.mp3` in that directory.

Comment: exactly, so how do i do that?  Why would putting a file in /httpdocs/music point to www.mywebsite.com/music?  By this path shouldn't the URL be www.mywebsite.com/httpdocs/music?

Comment: @GiH I am assuming the root URL, `http://www.example.com/` points to the `/httpdocs` directory.

Comment: it may need to be ftp://www.example.com/music/mysong.mp3

i think i got the syntax wrong, but basically put ftp: or ftp:// in front of the URL

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you are accessing the file with the exact same path as you used when copying it to `htdocs/`. Apache is case-sensitive.
2. Create a new file called `.htaccess` (don't miss the period) under `htdocs/` and put the following into it:

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor .jad
AddType application/java-archive .jar
```